How to chain two VPNs on MacOS to bypass blocked VPN
Question statement

I use MacOS and my company/uni VPN to access private resources of these organizations. These VPNs use unobfuscated protocols like WireGuard or OpenVPN.
I become unable to use these VPNs in restrictive countries where unobfuscated VPNs are blocked by protocol.
Protocols supporting obfuscation, e.g. ShadowSocks, are functioning just fine, however I am not able to change VPN protocols used by organizations I am a part of.

This problem can be solved by wrapping a company/uni VPN in an obfuscated VPN to bypass censorship. The question is then how do I route (chain) my MacOS traffic through two different VPNs without using extra hardware?
Mac -> Obfuscated VPN -> Organization VPN -> Internet
Specifically, I am interested in Outline -> Wireguard pair, but a more generic advice is also very much appreciated.
Working but unsatisfactory solutions:

Route traffic through a router/laptop with a setup obfuscated VPN. Use MacOS with an organization VPN as usual.

Why yes: allows to use Mac asif it was located in a non-restrictive location.
Why not: required to buy and carry a pretty large second physical device. Also, ARM routers don't support OutlineVPN (ShadowSocks) which I am using, so my solution was to use a laptop in a hotspot mode.


Access private resources via a VM with organization VPN installed, use obfuscated VPN on host. Worked with VMWare Fusion Ubuntu VM in Shared network mode.

Why yes: no extra hardware required.
Why not: able to access private resources only from a VM. Can't use apps on MacOS that require access to private resources, need to transfer all my work and study -related things to an inconvenient Linux VM.



Thoughts on potential solutions

Have some kind of virtual router(s) or VPN containers through which Mac traffic is going to be routed?
Solve this with a complex network configuration or VPN settings.


Use the VM solution but swap the VPNs over - the host handles Wireguard and the VM Outline. You will need to bridge the network adapter on the VM and forward all traffic from the host through the VM. I know how to do this on Linux, but I don't have sufficient knowledge of the Mac networking stack - hence this is comment not an answer.


how do I route (chain) my MacOS traffic through two different VPNs without using extra hardware?

You can't. That is, unless you control one of the VPN providers, which means extra hardware.
Each provider routes traffic as they see fit. There is no way for you to tell them to connect to another provider and route through them.
The only solution - if really required - is an external server that you control. Set up two VPN connections, one for you to dial in to and another to where you'd want the traffic to go through.
While you're at it, you might want to set up your dial-in VPN so that it is not easily detectable - use TCP port 443 with TLS, and so on.
(Yes, TCP over TCP sucks but it's better than nothing.)

A VPN is just an encrypted tunnel, on Linux you can nest as many tunnels as you want inside each other - hence this is totally possible on linux - I don't know enough about Mac networking to say if it is possible on Mac.

@DavidT Indeed, nesting might be possible, but chaining isn't.
